# AngularJS Component Library snippet generator?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, code-snippets

I'm trying to put together a library of custom AngularJS directives that show the live functioning component and underneath it the code snippet used to make that component.  I want the example and snippet to be generated from one shared html pattern.

I tried building a directive that copies the content of the div from the example as a string, but by the time that directive runs the component directives have already digested and made alterations to the DOM, making it a bad representation of how to build that component.

I don't want to use a codepen type solution, since I want everything to be under my server and my control, but I'm drawing a blank on how to show example snippets pre-AngularJS alteration.  There's no need to be able to have a live code editor, just something to copy snippets out of.

Comment: Side note: the reason I want to generate the example and the snippet from the same source is to prevent them from falling out of sync if I need to make adjustments in the future.

Comment: Not sure how you're serving this all up, but I think as long as those snippets aren't nested within something that has a controller, it will work like that.